# Are still alive/ just dragging the life/ just starving correct?

Tags: phrase-meaning, idiomatic-language

When someone says ' how are you?' and we want say that we are not fine at all. So in this situation how to respond?

Can I say: just dragging the life/ just starving/ still alive?
If I can't, what are natural ways to respond?

Comment: Can you expand on what *not fine* means in this context? There are a number of different ways to respond, at varying levels of seriousness/severity depending on what you mean.

Comment: Just about the *first* rule of social etiquette is that when someone says *How are you?*, you ***don't*** start telling them all your woes. It's just an introductory pleasantry for which the expected reply should be something like *Fine, thanks. And you?* If you reply with, for example, *So-so*, the other person will likely as not be irritated that you're effectively forcing them to ask for more details that they really don't want to know. The most "neutral" socially acceptable response I can think of is *Ticking along.*

Comment: What does 'TICKING ALONG' mean?

Comment: It's probably a BrE thing, based on ***to tick over*** (of an engine, to maintain [idle/idling speed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idle_speed)). Effectively, "functional, but not actually getting anywhere".

Answer (score 1):

First off, as @FumbleFingers mentioned, "How are you?" usually just means "Hello". As one of my favorite TV characters once said:

> When people say "good morning", they mean "hello". When people say "how are you", they mean "hello". When people say "wassup", they mean, "I am a person not worth talking to".

If you're just exchanging pleasantries, you can say, "I'm fine" or "I'm OK". These are neutral and natural.

> just dragging the life/just starving

The first one does not make grammatical sense. "Starving" only makes sense if you're really, really hungry.

"Still alive" comes across to me as darkly humorous - as in, "the only thing that I have to feel good about is that I'm still alive." However, like much dark humor, this can backfire. What if the person you say this to has just had a family member die? Now, things are awkward.

I suggest "hanging in there" as an alternative to "still alive".

---

The context matters a lot. If I'm passing by a co-worker that I hardly know, and we're going in opposite directions, we'll be interacting for 2 seconds (at most). If I say "how are you?" and they say, "I'm doing terribly", then I'm kind of obligated to stop and ask more. This may not be what either of us wants.

But if I'm having dinner with my best friend, and we're having an in-depth conversation, then "how are you?" may be a genuine question that we can go into in-depth.

Comment: +1 for *"wassup" means "I am a person not worth talking to"* (showing my credentials as a grumpy ole git! :). Actually, *Hanging in there* is probably a much more common "less than upbeat" response that doesn't necessarily force the polite well-wisher to ask you for further (unwanted) details.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to respond negatively to this common question, depending on how severely bad one is doing.

As a native English speaker, although I have not particularly heard it said before, *still alive* seems to make sense as a comical way to put it. The other two do not make much sense to me, but it is possible that this is because of regional differences.

The best way to respond negatively would be something along the lines of:

- *Not too well.*
- *I'm not doing too well.*
- *I'm just okay.*

Some more severe responses would be:

- *Horribly.*
- *Very bad.*

I hope that this information helps.